# Why the success of SCons build depends on variant_dir name?

Tags: fortran, scons

I am bored to death with such behavior. So in **SConstruct** file we have the last string like this one:

```
import compilers, os

env = Environment(ENV = os.environ, TOOLS = ['default'])

def set_compiler(compiler_name):
    env.Replace(FORTRAN = compiler_name)
    env.Replace(F77 = compiler_name)
    env.Replace(F90 = compiler_name)
    env.Replace(F95 = compiler_name)

def set_flags(flags):
    env.Replace(FORTRANFLAGS = flags)
    env.Replace(F77FLAGS = flags)
    env.Replace(F90FLAGS = flags)
    env.Replace(F95FLAGS = flags)

mod_dir_prefix = {
    "gfortran": "-J ",
    "ifort": "-???",
    "pgfortran": "-module " 
}

flags = {
    ("gfortran", "debug"): "-O0 -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fimplicit-none -fbounds-check -fbacktrace",
    ("gfortran", "release"): "-O3",
    ("pgfortran", "debug"): "-O0 -g -C -traceback",
    ("pgfortran",  "release"): "-O4"
}

if not GetOption('clean'):
    print "\nAvailable Fortran compilers:\n"

    for k, v in compilers.compilers_dict().iteritems():
        print "%10s : %s" % (k, v)

    compiler = raw_input("\nChoose compiler: ")

    set_compiler(compiler)

    debug_or_release = raw_input("\nDebug or release: ")

    set_flags(flags[(compiler, debug_or_release)])

    env.Replace(FORTRANMODDIRPREFIX = mod_dir_prefix[compiler])

    env.Replace(LINK = compiler)
    env.Replace(LINKCOM = "$LINK -o $TARGET $LINKFLAGS $SOURCES $_LIBDIRFLAGS $_LIBFLAGS $_FRAMEWORKPATH $_FRAMEWORKS $FRAMEWORKSFLAGS")
    env.Replace(LINKFLAGS = "")

env.Replace(FORTRANMODDIR = '#Mod')
Export('env')

SConscript('Sources/SConscript', variant_dir='Build', duplicate=0)
```

compilers.py is my own module to find some Fortran compilers which are available.

In Sources folder we have a couple of Fortran source files.

**Sources\SConscript**

```
Import('env')
env.Program('app', Glob('*.f90'))
```

Scons supports Fortran and everything works fine.

```
gfortran -o Temp\kinds.o -c -O3 -JMod Sources\kinds.f90
gfortran -o Temp\math.o -c -O3 -JMod Sources\math.f90
gfortran -o Temp\sorts.o -c -O3 -JMod Sources\sorts.f90
gfortran -o Temp\utils.o -c -O3 -JMod Sources\utils.f90
gfortran -o Temp\main.o -c -O3 -JMod Sources\main.f90
gfortran -o Temp\app.exe Temp\kinds.o Temp\main.o Temp\math.o Temp\sorts.o Temp\utils.o
scons: done building targets.
```

After renaming variant_dir name to let say `#Bin` or `#Build` we get error message:

```
gfortran -o Bin\kinds.o -c -O3 -JMod Sources\kinds.f90
gfortran -o Bin\main.o -c -O3 -JMod Sources\main.f90
Sources\main.f90:3.11:

  USE sorts
           1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'sorts.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
```

Of course the order of compilation matters. But why it depends on variant_dir name? Seems like a bug, but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

P.S. This behavior doesn't depend on `duplicate` variable value.
P.P.S. Tested with SCons 2.0.1 on Windows with Python 2.7 and Mac OS X with Python 2.5.1.

Comment: @kemiisto: it's enough to drive you to make.

Comment: @High Performance Mark: me and make are from different eras. Build tools without automatic dependency analysis are not even under consideration. CMake is too heavy and at the same time too restrictive and not enough flexible for me.

Comment: Can you show the Sources/SConscript file? Have you tried to use 'Temp' or 'Bin' as the variant dirs? Instead of '#Temp' and '#Bin'.

Comment: @dantje: I tried to use variant dir name without # symbol. It doesn't matter. I'll edit my question to include SConscript file.

Comment: The F90 Scanner apparently can't detect use statements in includes (
http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-api/SCons.Scanner.Fortran-pysrc.html) Is this the case in your sources?

Comment: @dantje: I do not use any INCLUDE statements. And (once again) dependency analysis works without variant directory and with some variant directories having "special" names.

Comment: Are you explicitly setting -JMod in your logic, or setting _FORTRANMODFLAG to -J and letting SCons generate the command line?

Answer (score 1):

This is a reply to an old thread, but I had virtually the same problem and needed to dig around for a solution.

Firstly, your build order is probably off because the dependency scanner for Fortran does not work properly. Try running

```
scons [your_arguments] -n --tree=all | less
```

which won't actually compile anything but show you the commands and in the end will print the dependency tree as Scons sees it.

A possible solution:

Try adding the line (I added your source for context):

`env.Replace(FORTRANMODDIR = '#Mod')
env.Replace(FORTRANPATH = '.' ]
Export('env')`

As far as I understand, paths are relative to the "virtual" location of the SConscript file (i.e. the src directory or the variant `build` directory), this should add the directory containing the source files to the scanner's search path.

In my version of scons (2.3.0), I cannot use the `duplicate=0` argument, since it automatically inserts the original source directory into the module path, causing the command line to look like `-module build/ -module src/` (ifort) and essentially overriding my preference not to clutter the source directory. This might be a bug, though.